# Need a marquee tag replacement allowing display of multiple images

Tags: php, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:
Display a marquee composed of several (dozen or more) company logos, across the page from right to left in a single row.

I have the following code which works as desired in Firefox, but doesn't work in other (Chrome, IE, Edge) browsers.
Specifically, if the width of the combined images is greater than the width of the div, the overflow images are displayed on another "line" below, starting at the far left. It seems the duration of the display is as if the images are properly in line (as there is a great deal of blank space / time  after the last image clears the div edge.

I have tried to use suggested CSS3, and the swimming fish js examples, but they only work with a single image. I'm using php to get multiple images from mysql, they don't fit my needs.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>



<div id="wrap">
<div id="header" align="left">
<br>
<font color="gray">
<p align="right">Over <font color="maroon"><b>500,000 </b></font>flags placed since 2012</p> 
</font>
<p><img src="dialmiller.jpg" width="200" height="200" style="vertical-align: middle"/>

<span style="display:inline-block" align="right">
<font size="7">Flags for Fallen Vets </font><font size="5">.com </font>
</span> 
<figcaption><font color="gray">Never Forgotten</font></figcaption>

</p>

<p class ="social" align="middle">
<a href="#"><font color="black" size="5"><b>Donate</b></font></a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/flagsforfallenvets/"><img src="fb.png" width="20" height="20" align="right"/></a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="twr.jpg" width="20" height="20" align="right"/></a>
</p>


</div>
<ul id="menu">
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">National Cemeteries</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dallas-Fort Worth</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<li><a href="#">Houston</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<li><a href="#">Florida</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<li><a href="#">Sarasota</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<li><a href="#">South Florida</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<li><a href="#">Black Hills</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

<li><a href="#">Fort Meade</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="newvolunteer.php">Volunteer Form</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sponsor Levels</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2017 Shirts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>

 <div class="main"> 

<h4 align="center"> Sponsors </h4> 
      <?php
       $fetch=mysql_query("select * from banners ORDER by level");
       if(mysql_num_rows($fetch))
          {
      ?>


  <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="5" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">


       <ul class="ulclass" >
             <?php 
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
                 {
                 $id=$row['id'];
                 $feed= $row['image'];

               ?>
           <li class="liclassleft">
           <?php echo '<img src="img/banners/'.$feed.'"'.' width="125" height="125";'; ?>
           <?php }  ?>
           </li>
           <?php }  ?>  
      </ul>

</marquee>

</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<!-- CONTENT -->
<p>

 oeprjjiowerf wergui c uiweriu2mu[i3r 2wemu  [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i
qerogpwejpiwepmkvpqervm  oeprjjiowerf wergui c uiweriu2mu[i3r 2wemu  [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i
qerogpwejpiwepmkvpqervm  oeprjjiowerf wergui c uiweriu2mu[i3r 2wemu  [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i
qerogpwejpiwepmkvpqervm  oeprjjiowerf wergui c uiweriu2mu[i3r 2wemu  [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i [po23ior  34iopgti34tg 345ti,345t-0,i

</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Important CSS lines used:

```
.main { border-bottom:1px #051B42 solid; max-width:99%;max-height:195px; padding:5px; float:left; margin-bottom:1px; }

.ulclass { list-style-type:none;}

.liclassleft { margin:0 auto; border-bottom:1px #808080; font-size:20px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px;float: left;}
```

I understand the `<marquee>` tag isn't what I should be using, but except for the wrapping of images it works.
I'm open to using any form of replacement.

Comment: You can use pure CSS for the marquee effect. Here is a simple tutorial - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa what do you mean you can't create a marquee effect with CSS? Sure you can: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/jy8potyf/

Comment: @Russ the problem here is that no one can tell the actual size of the content because we can't run the PHP. Please post processed HTML rather than the PHP. That way we can see the *entire* HTML entity rather than the just loop script.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - Yes I can use CSS to create a marquee effect. But I can't get the problem of "image wrapping" to go away. The problem seems related to 2 things I'm doing that are not in the CSS examples: using images rather than just text & using multiple images that stretch beyond the div limits.

Comment: Scott, see updated HTML. Excuse me this is my first question on Stack Overflow. I don't know the proper etiquette.

Comment: Not a problem at all Russ. But even with the update I can't tell how many images are in the marquee div so I can't really troubleshoot width issues. Don't need the head and navigation, but need to see how many images are in the marquee *after* the loop processes. Can you copy/paste source code from the rendered page for just the marquee tag??

Comment: FYI... I have an idea on how to solve this, which is possibly rather easy to implement... but I'd rather to provide tested markup than just guessing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that. I can tell you there are 14 images, padded 10px apart - each measuring 125px W X 125px H.

Comment: Scott, looks great from the snippet. I will have time tonight to incorporate the code into the page & test it thoroughly. Should this work with my php / MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.....

It should work with any number of images, but the animation end percentage may need some minor adjustment as desired.

```css
.marqHold {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 135px; /* image height+padding */
  }

 .marqHold ul { 
    list-style: none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 110%; /* positions ul off screen to start */
    animation: marq 8s linear infinite; /* 8s = 8 seconds, adjust as desired */
 }

 .marqHold ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

@keyframes marq {
  from { left: 110%; }
  to { left: -200%; } /* increase/decrease to set point where animation restarts */
  }
```

```html
<div class="marqHold">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Move to right:

```css
.marqHold {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background: #aaa;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 20px 0;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 135px; /* image height+padding */
  }

 .marqHold ul { 
   list-style: none; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
    position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
   left: -200%; /* positions ul off screen to start */
   animation: marq 8s linear infinite;
 }

 .marqHold ul li { 
      display: inline-block;
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
       padding: 5px;
  }

@keyframes marq {
  from { left: -200%;
    }
  to { left: 110%; } 
  }
```

```html
<div class="marqHold">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Bounce back and forth.....

```css
.marqHold {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background: #aaa;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 20px 0;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 135px; /* image height+padding */
  }

 .marqHold ul { 
   list-style: none; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
    position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
   left: -200%; /* positions ul off screen to start */
   animation: marq 10s linear infinite;
 }

 .marqHold ul li { 
      display: inline-block;
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
       padding: 5px;
  }

@keyframes marq {
  0% { left: -200%;
    }
 50% { left: 110%; } 
 100% { left: -200%; } 
  }
```

```html
<div class="marqHold">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
<li>
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&bg=112255&txt=125%C3%97125&w=125&h=125" width="125" height="125" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Scott, That worked to keep all images in a single row. Only 2 minor changes: after 1 cycle both scroll bars appear, stay on until 2nd cycle is done & disappear. This repeats. Secondly, I'd like the marquee effect to stay within the inner boundaries of the page. They seem like a layer on top of the web page - rather have them in a stationary div between my horizontal menu & the actual content of the page. Right now, it's superimposed over the content. Thanks.

Comment: @Russ StackOverflow is not a code writing service. It's somewhat expected that you will attempt to fix your own issues first.

Comment: Scott, Thank you. I didn't mean for you to do that. Comment was meant to tell you what I needed to solve - that's part of the fun of coding - the challenges. I solved the positioning by padding-top: 135px. I looked up removing scroll bars & found references to using overflow-x: hidden;.This worked as soon as I positioned the line under html.

Comment: No problem Russ. Sorry if I came off a bit gruff... It's difficult to tell in text the users that want to be spoon fed and those that just want pointed in the right direction. Glad you got things sorted :)